# AVR-libc `uart_putchar` implementation

Tags: c, stream, fopen, avr, avr-gcc

In  [AVR-libc page 143](https://cours.polymtl.ca/inf1900/logiciel/progAvr/avr-libc-user-manual-2.0.0.pdf) the implementation of the function `uart_putchar()` is typical as the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream);

static FILE mystdout = FDEV_SETUP_STREAM(uart_putchar, NULL, _FDEV_SETUP_WRITE);

static int
uart_putchar(char c, FILE *stream)
{
if (c == '\n')
  uart_putchar('\r', stream);
loop_until_bit_is_set(UCSRA, UDRE);
UDR = c;
return 0;
}
int
main(void)
{
  init_uart();
  stdout = &mystdout;
  printf("Hello, world!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I know that we can redirect a specific stream to a `stdout` or `stdin` using `fdevopen()`.

But is not the variable `stream` is not used in this function?
Why is there such a variable that not used by the function? Is that because the `fdevopen()` pointers to functions parameters?

Comment: Can you link the avr-libc you got that definition of `uart_putchar` from?

Comment: @P.p OK. Just linked it.

Comment: On page 143, `uart_putchar` does use `stream`: `uart_putchar(’\r’, stream);`

Comment: But it's a recursive call to the same function. The object `stream` never used. It only passed to the same function that does not use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a simple example where there is only one thing to print to, so there is no need to check the `stream` argument.

If you were going to implement something more complicated where you could print to multiple serial streams using functions like `fprintf` that take a `FILE *` argument, then you would use the `stream` argument to figure out where the caller wanted to send characters to, and then make sure the characters go to the right place.  I think most embedded AVR programs do not need that, but `avr-libc` gives you the ability to do that anyway.